# i can't render a image in pdf-creator-node header

Tags: javascript, node.js, html-pdf, node-html-pdf, pdfcreator

```
const options = {
        format: 'Letter',
        orientation: 'portrait',
        border: '0mm',
        header: {
            contents: `
            <div class="headerPDF">
                <img src="https://helpx.adobe.com/content/dam/help/en/photoshop/using/convert-color-image-black-white/jcr_content/main-pars/before_and_after/image-before/Landscape-Color.jpg"/>
                <h1>test</h1>
            </div>
            <style>
                .headerPDF{
                    width: 90%;
                    height: 60%;
                    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
                }
                .headerPDF > img{
                    width: 100px;
                    border: 1px solid black;
                }
            </style>
            `,
        },
        footer: {
            height: '0mm',
            contents: '',
        },
        childProcessOptions: { env: { OPENSSL_CONF: '/dev/null' } },
    }
```

This is a code of options and this image, don't render for nothing

[image]

and this is the output of the code

i try to put the path in the variable and i try to change many options